# How to check whether my system RAM is DDR2 or DDR3

Tags: memory

I have a compac desktop computer and I want to update it with the 2 or 3 GB or RAM. I am confused that what type of RAM this system have whether ***DDR2 or DDR3***. The processor in my computer is AMD Athlon.

So, if possible please let me know, the ways how can I check the type of RAM whether DDR2 or DDR3.

And how can I check by looking at the RAM that what type of this.

Answer (score 16):

Try CPUID:

Direct Download:
http://download.cpuid.com/cpu-z/cpu-z_1.74-en.exe

Downloads: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

After you installed it, go to the Memory tab, your answer is there.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

DDR2 ram has a sticker on the dimms labelled PC2-xxxx
DDR3 ram has a sticker on the dimms labelled PC3-xxxx(x)

Even if there is just a barcode on it, you can google the number and it will show you what type of memory it is.

You can also visit a site like kingston.com or crucial.com, enter the details of your computer make and model, and it will give you a list of compatible memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you can't or don't want open your computer, may be the free tool Speccy (System Information) will give you the information. You can download it on [Piriform web page](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) , choosing the free version.

Also you can find a portable version on [Speccy - Download Builds](http://www.piriform.com/speccy/builds) just in case you don't want to install in your PC.

Comment: since CPUz no longer has a portable version in its latest versions. Speccy is a great alternative. thanks for pointing that out.